# Is it possible to execute shell commands within a mac application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, compilation, ocaml

Basically I'm wondering if I can compile code that a user inputs in a mac app (I'm trying to make an OCaml text editor that compiles your code) using executables that are already available in the user's system, such as `ocamlc` etc. I don't have any code to show or anything because I'm still figuring out if/how I could build this mac app. Not really sure what other info I should include, so just ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Objective-C, check out [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If not, look at [popen](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/popen.3.html).  popen gives your parent process control over the I/O streams.

Comment: NSTask looks interesting, I'll have to figure out how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use either `Sys.command "<your shell command>"` or `Unix.open_process*` and `Unix.create_process` commands. See `man Sys` and `man Unix` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C, C, and C++, and a multitude of other languages, use [`system(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system). Also see:

- [`exec(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec)
- [`popen(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/popen.3.html)